# My app lags for about a couple of seconds before it become responsive again

Tags: android, multithreading

Everytime I select the consultation_fragment on my navigation drawer it lags for a couple of seconds before it become responsive again.

Here's my code

```
private Handler aHandler = new Handler();
View rootView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    rootView = lf.inflate(R.layout.consultation_fragment, container, false);

    aHandler.postDelayed(r, 0);
    return rootView;
}

public void sTest()
{
    viewDeclaration();
    visitorInfo();
    chat = ZopimChatApi.start(getActivity());
    Log.d("ChatHasEnded: ", String.valueOf(chat.hasEnded()));
    accountObserver = new AccountObserver()
    {
        @Override
        public void update(final Account account)
        {
            final Account.Status status = account.getStatus();
            if (status != null)
                if(getActivity() != null)
                {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            switch (status)
                            {
                                case ONLINE:
                                    mStatus.setText("Therapist is Online");
                                    mConsultation.setEnabled(true);
                                    ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.online);
                                    break;
                                case UNKNOWN:
                                case OFFLINE:
                                    mStatus.setText("Therapist is Offline");
                                    mConsultation.setEnabled(false);
                                    ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
        }
    };
    // listen for account events
    ZopimChatApi.getDataSource().addAccountObserver(accountObserver);
}

final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        sTest();
    }
};
```

if I check the logcat it shows this error

I/Choreographer: Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/Choreographer: Skipped 131 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/Choreographer: Skipped 131 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/Choreographer: Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/Choreographer: Skipped 128 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/Choreographer: Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/Choreographer: Skipped 130 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/Choreographer: Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

UPDATE:

The culprit was the changing of the image resource of my ImageView. Is there any way to prevent this? I really want to load image resource on runOnUiThread without having the error of skipped frames

Comment: `aHandler` does it on the main thread. If you want to do this on a separate thread, use a HandlerThread and instantiate that Handler with the HanlderThread as an argument

Comment: @Twometer I found the culprit of the skipping frames. When I don't update my imageview it is smooth but when I include it it is so slow. How can I prevent it? I really want to include picture in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that one of my picture in drawable has a resolution of 2000x2000 so I tried resizing it to like 25x25 now it never lags.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads I´m not a programmer but i see that this happens when the program/app make a loop reading the code, you should verify the switch case with the if i think that the problem is there but by using the null. Here is another post with the same issue:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67790/obtengo-el-mensaje-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thr